# The four knights (rileys)

Tags: story, affix-riddle

> Four knights were on four hills, some on higher hills than others.
>
> The first spoke, and he said:
> “I begin with my “for” noun,
> then the one next to me is tumblin’ down,
> then I… um… ummmm… yeah that’s all I remember.”
> He had a sign with the hashtag “#MeToo” on it.
>
> The second one spoke,
> “My start is new, to the Romans,
> the next is a very, very long time to say,
> and my finish makes sure you shalt see!
> Oh, and so do I.”
> He was carrying a sign saying: “Subscribe to TopTens!”
>
> Then the third, oft mistaken for land, arrived. He said:
> “My first is a [[HYPERLINK BLOCKED]]
> My middle is really [[STINKING]] good.
> My finale is the same as the second [[HYPERLINK BLOCKED]]
> And together, I am confused with those LITTLE FRENCH LAND-“
> He storms out with his new driver’s license, and hops on his horse, named “Lambourginie”.
>
> Then, you’re prepared to walk to the king’s chamber and tell him the knight’s names when…
>
> “hey. it’s me…
> i suppose i should have a riddle…
> well, i’m oft overlooked, and confused with an übermensch’s death,
> my start is what this is, minus “ick”…
> my end is the last two’s.
> enjoy, i guess.”
>
> Undeterred, you walk into the king’s room and tells him the name of the knights. He tells you his name in return.
>
> Sounded Russian.

**What are the four knights' names?**

Optional: **What's the king's name?**

SMØL HINT, BY IKEA:

> Those little French lands have a lot of dead bodies. R.I.P.

MÆDIUM HINT, BY IKEA:

> They sit at a *NON* round table, and its bench is unstable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the four knights are

> Helium, Neon, Argon and Krypton (the first four noble gases)

The king is probably

> Dmitri Mendeleev, who created the periodic table of elements

The first spoke, and he said:
“I begin with my “for” noun,

> My guess here is that "for" noun is a cryptic way of describing a *pro*noun which in this case is **He**.

then the one next to me is tumblin’ down

> Not totally sure about this part but I think it refers to the fact that the next element in the periodic table is Lithium (**Li**) which is the next part of the word Helium.

then I… um… ummmm… yeah that’s all I remember.”

> The last part of Helium is **um**

He had a sign with the hashtag “#MeToo” on it.

> MeToo sounds like "me two" referring to the fact that Helium is the second element of the periodic table.

The second one spoke,
“My start is new, to the Romans,

> I think this refers to **Neo**, (although this actually has Greek etymology rather than Latin so I might be wrong about this (yes, OP can confirm, I messed these up))

the next is a very, very long time to say,

> **Eon**

and my finish makes sure you shalt see!

> I think this refers to **on** (as in something being turned on, such as a light switch).

Oh, and so do I.”

> Neon is often used in signs and produces a reddish-orange light.

He was carrying a sign saying: “Subscribe to TopTens!”

> Neon has atomic number 10.

Then the third, oft mistaken for land, arrived. He said:
“My first is a [[HYPERLINK BLOCKED]]

> Here just saying that the first letter is **a**

My middle is really [[STINKING]] good.

> **rg** is an acronym for *really good*

My finale is the same as the second [[HYPERLINK BLOCKED]]

> Arg**on** has the same ending as Ne**on**

And together, I am confused with those LITTLE FRENCH LAND-“

> I think this refers to [Argonne](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forest_of_Argonne) (Yes, it does, according to OP)

He storms out with his new driver’s license, and hops on his horse, named “Lambourginie”.

> Not sure about this bit other than the middle part of the word sounds a bit like *argon*

“hey. it’s me…
i suppose i should have a riddle…
well, i’m oft overlooked, and confused with an übermensch’s death,

> The übermensch is Superman whose weakness is *kryptonite*, often confused with **Krypton**, and “oft overlooked” refers to its status as a not very noticeable element.

my start is what this is, minus “ick”…

> **Krypt**ick sounds like *cryptic*

my end is the last two’s.

> Krypt**on** has the same ending as Ne**on** and Arg**on**.

OP SMALL INCLUSION:

> The four knights refers to them being **noble** gases. *rimshot*

Comment: Upvote if you can explain the second hint :) but you’re right!